# How do I sort numbers as per their order?

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I have a **CodeIgniter (MVC)** based system where there a column of number is coming all messed up, can anyone tell me how can I sort them in **ascending order**?

FYI

[image]

**Thank you!**

Comment: Post your code and given data

Comment: use $this->db->order_by("your_column_name", "asc");

Comment: Its not messed up, you're just storing it wrong so its treated as a string.

Comment: You've already answered your question. You can use `sort()` More info here  http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=order_by#CI_DB_query_builder::order_by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an order_by will not help if you are storing the values as `VARCHAR` datatype, you should instead use `INT`.

[image]

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3a913/3/0

Answer (score 2):

Its not messing up but ,Records are listing in order by stored 'id'.
all you need to get all records in ascending order of roll number .

If you do not have any column for roll number, then you have to add new column for roll number in table . 
Then get records by ascending order of roll number.by adding

```
$this->db->order_by("roll_no_column_name", "asc");
```

Into your function from with you are fetching this data in your model.

Answer (score 1):

Put order_by after where clause:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('table_name');
$this->db->where('id',$id);
$this->db->order_by("column_name","desc");
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('user');
$this->db->order_by('roll_no', 'asc');
$query = $this->db->get();
return $query->result();
```